# Help to confirm word I heard on television show "Sekkai!"

Tags: words

I heard this word often and I'm pretty sure it means "correct! / right! / great!" but I cannot seem to find the word in dictionary and I don't even know how it is written. I try to find せっかい but have no match.

Could you help to confirm what word am I hearing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be thinking of seikai, 正{せい}解{かい}

I hear it often used in game-shows indicating the contestant got the correct answer. It's hard to know for sure since you aren't providing a whole lot of context, but this would be my best guess.

Definition (according to jisho.org)

- 正{せい}解{かい}: correct; right; correct interpretation (answer, solution)

Comment: I believe it's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much.